# How can I proprerly use an instance variable in a link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, link-to

How can I resolve this ?

I had 2 buttons :
/views/subjects/_inscription_button.html.haml

```
  - if subject.participation(current_participant).nil?
    = link_to "Ca m'intéresse !",   subject_participant_index_path(:interested_id => current_participant.id, :subject_id => subject.id), remote: true, :method => :post, class:"btn btn-primary"

  - else
    = link_to "Ca ne m'intéresse plus !",   delete_participation_path(@subject.participation(current_participant).id),:method => :delete, remote: true, class:"btn btn-primary"
```

The second `link_to` doesn't want to switch properly. I get the error :

> NoMethodError at /subject_participant/115 
>   undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

The instance variable `subject` works for the first button but not the second...

Here is the rest of the usefull code :
subject_participant_controller.rb :

```
class SubjectParticipantController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_participant!


  def create
   @subject = Subject.find(params[:subject_id])
   @subject_participant = SubjectParticipant.new(subject_participant_params)

   if @subject_participant.save
     respond_to do | format |
      format.html {redirect_to subjects_path}
      format.js
     end
   else
    redirect_to subjects_path
   end
  end

  def destroy
    @subject_participant = SubjectParticipant.find(params[:id])
    if @subject_participant.destroy
     respond_to do | format |
      format.html {redirect_to subjects_path}
      format.js
     end
    else
     redirect_to subjects_path
    end
  end

  def subject_participant_params
    params.permit(:interested_id, :subject_id, :id)
  end
end
```

/routes.rb :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 devise_for :participants
 resources :subjects
 resources :participants
 resources :conferences
 resources :subject_participant

 delete 'subject_participant/:id' => 'subject_participant#destroy', as: 'delete_participation'
 root 'welcome#index'
```

subject.rb

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of  :title, :questioner, :conference, :description

  has_many :subject_participants
  has_many :interested, through: :subject_participants #interested
  belongs_to :questioner, class_name: "Participant"
  belongs_to :conference

  def participation(current_participant) 
   self.subject_participants.find_by_interested_id(current_participant.id)
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you that `@subject.participation(current_participant)` is nil. You need to fix it.

Remember that when using instance variables in Rails views, you need to define them in the corresponding controller action. Step backwards from your partial to its parent view. Which controller action is it tied to?

This is where you will define instance variables needed in your partial.

Comment: Yes it's nil because the method cannot access to the variable `subject` present in the views. This is actually my problem

Comment: You're calling `id` on `@subject.participation(current_participant)`. `@subject.participation(current_participant)` is nil, and that's your problem. You need to begin debugging your application with that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Just user @subject in place of subject.

```
- if subject.participation(current_participant).nil?
= link_to "Ca m'intéresse !",subject_participant_index_path(:interested_id => current_participant.id, :subject_id => @subject.id), remote: true, :method => :post, class:"btn btn-primary"

- else
= link_to "Ca ne m'intéresse plus !",   delete_participation_path(@subject.participation(current_participant).id),:method => :delete, remote: true, class:"btn btn-primary"
```

Comment: It sends me an other error `undefined method 'participation' for nil:NilClass `